# Libgdx show tooltip

Tags: java, label, tooltip, libgdx

I am developing a game with libgdx. This game contains different Levels, which are rendered by a Stage. All objects in that Level are represented by libgdx Actors. Now I want to have a tutorial Level. In this Level a tooltip should show when the Player reaches a specific Position within the Level. This tooltip should contain informations (like: "Press A to go left!") and dissapear after some time. I thought about using libgdx Label and add a Sequence of Actions to them (•Delay 5s •FadeOut in 1s).
The Problem is that for Labels I need to create a `LabelStyle` for which I have to create a `Font` file and load it.
Is there a way to create a Label with a default font (like ARIAL or others)? It should just be easy to read nothing more. Or is there another easy way to create this kind of tooltips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful how you're using the term "tooltip". I don't think what you're talking about is actually a tooltip, just a message displayed on the screen.

If you want to display text in libGDX, you should do the work and use a real font. But for quick-and-dirty rendering, you can use the BitmapFont class. Something like this:

```
BitmapFont font = new BitmapFont();
font.setColor(Color.WHITE);
font.setScale(2f);
font.draw(batch, "FPS: " + Gdx.graphics.getFramesPerSecond(), 25, 25);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Ist exactly what i Need. I thought i have to load a font from a file...